# How to Securely Serialise a Plutus Smart Contract Endpoint?

Tags: cardano-serialization-lib, smart-contract

Assuming I made an arbitrary smart contract and want to serialise the endpoint after I have the validator hash and address hash, what should I do to ensure that the serialisation is as safe as possible?

are there steps I should follow to make minimum security guarantees or some software I can use to test it? How do I know that the serialisation is done correctly?

Comment: The current format of the question is a bit vague. Could you try to rephrase it? Are you trying to assert if you contract is safe to use from a design perspective? Or if the serialization does what it is meant to do?

Comment: Okay thanks for the input, I'll rewrite it when I'm on my laptop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before I can answer there is an important distinction that must be done

**on-chain code can be serialized, off-chain code stays "off the chain" so there is nothing to serialize**

so if you are searching for a way to serialize your off-chain code (which can be written in any language, from Haskell with the `Contract` monad to javascript thanks to the `cardano-serialization-library`) unfortunately there is nothing to do

### serialize the on-chain code

from the chain point of view there is no difference between `Validator`s and `MintingPolicy`(ies) and `StakeValidator`

all of them are `Script`s for the chain, treated differently based on the `ScriptPourpose` of that transaction

so you first need to get the raw `Script` of your smart contract

you can do that with the following functions (all form [`Plutus.V1.Ledger.Api` module](https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V1-Ledger-Api.html))

```
unValidatorScript :: Validator -> Script
getMintingPolicy :: MintingPolicy -> Script
getStakeValidator :: StakeValidator -> Script
```

once you have your `Script` the process is always the same

`Script` has an instance of the `Srialize` typeclass which conviniently exposes the `serialise` function:

```
serialise :: forall a. Serialise a => a -> ByteString
```

then we need to **strictly evaluate** the byte-string and make sure the values do fit in `short`s types, this can be done by concatenating the following two functions

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Short          as SBS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy           as LBS

-- LBS.toStrict :: ByteString -> ByteString
-- SBS.toShort :: ByteString -> ShortByteString
asStrictBS :: ByteString -> ShortByteString
asStrictBS = SBS.toShort . LBS.toStrict
```

then we have to specify how to interpret the `ShortByteString` we have:

```
-- PlutusScriptSerialized is a constrctor
PlutusScriptSerialized :: ShortByteString -> PlutusScript PlutusScriptV1
```

and finally get our `Script` into a file, which can be done thanks to the `writeFileTextEnvelope` from the `Cardano.Api.SerialiseTextEnvelope` module:

```
writeFileTextEnvelope :: forall a.
HasTextEnvelope a =>
FilePath
-> Maybe TextEnvelopeDescr -> a -> IO (Either (FileError ()) ())
```

I usually do all this whit the following utility funciutons:

```
getAndWriteScript :: ( willBeScript -> Ledger.Script ) -> FilePath -> willBeScript -> IO (Either (FileError ()) ())
getAndWriteScript getScript filePath =
--                          PlutusScript PlutusScriptV1 instance of HasTextEnvelope  
    writeFileTextEnvelope @(PlutusScript PlutusScriptV1) filePath
    Nothing -- Maybe TextEnvelopeDescr ( Nothing => default )
    . PlutusScriptSerialised . SBS.toShort . LBS.toStrict . serialise . getScript

writeMintingPolicy :: FilePath -> Scripts.MintingPolicy -> IO (Either (FileError ()) ())
writeMintingPolicy = getAndWriteScript Ledger.getMintingPolicy

writeValidator :: FilePath -> Scripts.Validator -> IO (Either (FileError ()) ())
writeValidator = getAndWriteScript Ledger.unValidatorScript
```

Comment: Also have a look at https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-ledger-api/html/Plutus-V2-Ledger-Api.html#v:validateScript. This functions checks if a `SerializedScript` is correctly serialized.